# Running seed in web application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, seed

I want to run database seed from my web application on server.

I have created my command, I have

```
$resp = Artisan::call('migrate', ['--path' => 'database/migrations/create_database/']);
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');
Artisan::call('db:seed');
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
```

I start it by command `Artisan::call('myCommand:run');` in my function.
Localy this works, migration and seed completed with success.

When I want to run it on serwer and start it by my endpoint only migrations run.
I have that error in log file

```
[2020-08-27 10:35:18] local.ERROR: Class AclPermissionTableSeeder does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class AclPermissionTableSeeder does not exist at /devs/dev.rps.zoneit.pl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:779)
[stacktrace]
#0 /devs/dev.domain.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(779): ReflectionClass->__construct('AclPermissionTa...')
```

And this is the first seed.

Is this properly run seed in app, or I can't run database seed in web app?

Comment: I assume you can't use `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

before run `Artisan::call('db:seed');`

u need to run `composer dump-autoload` so your all seeder class get loaded to laravel application